How can I rewrite this code using CRTP approach?
I had a static hard-coded test code. After that I have transformed it into dynamic binding to test the performance, and virtual calls appeared to be approximately two times slower.
#include <vector>

class vUnit {
  public:
    virtual ~vUnit() {;}
    virtual float process(float f) = 0;
};

class vRack {
  public:
    vRack() {;}
    ~vRack() {;}
    
    inline void addUnit(vUnit* unit_ptr) {
      _units.push_back(unit_ptr);
    }
    
    inline float process_all(float  f) { 
      float  res = 0.;
      for (int j = 0 ; j< 60; j++) {
        for (auto u : _units) {
          f = u->process(f);
        }
      }
      res += f;
      return res;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<vUnit*>  _units ; 
    int _i = 0;
};


class vMultiplyF : public vUnit {
  public:
    vMultiplyF(float v) {_f = v;}
    inline float process(float f) final {
      return f * _f;
    }
  private:
    float  _f;
};

class vDivideF : public vUnit {
  public:
    vDivideF(float v) {_f = v;}
    inline float process(float f) final {
      if (f > 0) {
        return _f / f;
      } else return 0.0f;
    }
  private:
    float  _f;
};

int main () {
  float f = 1.5f, r = 0.0f;
  vRack       vR;
  vMultiplyF  vM(5.1f);
  vDivideF    vD(5.5f);

  vR.addUnit(&vM);
  vR.addUnit(&vD);

  for( int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    f = vR.process_all(f);
    r += f;
  }
  return 0;
}

I think that CRTP could be a reasonable compromise, but I don't quite get how I can rewrite vRack.addUnit() so that it could take different vUnit implementations. Can anyone help?

Took the liberty to edit your code to initialize variables (I would find it strange if your compiler lets you do float f; then vR.process_all(f);).

How do you measure your 2x difference in performance?

I run both versions on an MCU measuring times accordingly

you need a common base class to place objects of different type into a std::vector<pointer to base>. CRTP has no common base class. Its unclear what you expect to get from CRTP

I don't think you can implement static polymorphism in this case; if you really need to handle a container holding objects having different runtime types, what you did seems to be the only way to go.

"....and virtual calls appeared to be approximately two times slower." a factor of x2 is unlikely. Its more likely that the difference between the other code and the new code is more than just a virtual call. Its hard to say without seeing the code

OK you misunderstood. Please post the benchmark code and explain how you run it, what are the testing data, are the results not accidentally optimized-out, compiler options, hardware (if relevant).

See std::variant, boost has an implementation if your MCU library doesn't provide one (i see vector so who knows)

FYI, I benched your code against the version where class vRack holds hardcoded non-polymorphic types, and the execution times differ by ~2% in favour of no dynamic dispatch.

@pptaszni modern computers predict the virtual function call, MCUs don't

@AhmedAEK I would expect visiting a variant to perform similarly to a virtual function call

@Caleth it has slightly less overhead 1 dereference vs 2

@pptaszni https://gist.github.com/copych/a4e11bdb0604fac7549382936794bf6c ESP32S3 is the target

@Caleth most modern computers have the same performance for the variant and the virtual call because they predict things and prefetch and reorder instructions, an MCU won't, visiting a variant will be faster than a virtual call.

O, with ESP32S3 as a target, it makes more sense. Then yeah, container of std::variant could be faster.


I think that CRTP could be a reasonable compromise.

CRTP doesn't help you here. You need some indirection to distinguish your different operations.
If the configuration is static, then you can swap from iterating a container of vUnits to using a fold expression to combine a tuple of specific objects.
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
concept Unit = requires(T unit, float f) { f = unit.process(f); };

class vMultiplyF { // No base class needed
  public:
    vMultiplyF(float v) {_f = v;}
    float process(float f) {
      return f * _f;
    }
  private:
    float  _f;
};

class vDivideF { // No base class needed
  public:
    vDivideF(float v) {_f = v;}
    float process(float f) {
      if (f > 0) {
        return _f / f;
      } else return 0.0f;
    }
  private:
    float  _f;
};

template <Unit... Units>
class vRack {
  public:
    vRack(Units... units) : _units(std::move(units)...) {}
    float process_all(float  f) { 
      for (int j = 0 ; j< 60; j++) {
        // evaluates (f = unit.process(f)) for each unit in sequence
        std::apply([&](Units&... unit){ ((f = unit.process(f)), ...); }, _units);
      }
      return f;
    }

  private:
    std::tuple<Units...>  _units; 
};

int main () {
  float f = 1.5f, r = 0.0f;
  vMultiplyF  vM(5.1f);
  vDivideF    vD(5.5f);
  vRack       vR(vM, vD); // deduces vRack<vMultiplyF, vDivideF>

  for( int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    f = vR.process_all(f);
    r += f;
  }
  return 0;
}


Thank you , I will test it along with the two that I have

One could have less "static" configuration by adding to vRack the following method: template <Unit... U> auto add (U...units) { return vRack<Units...,U...> (std::tuple_cat (_units, std::make_tuple (units...))); }, then one can get new rack by adding some units to an already existing rack, e.g. auto vR2 = vR.add (vD);. Note however that the two racks won't have the same type.
